# set of numbers satisfying a complex exponential equation

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the question:

Using the principle branch definition of $z^i$ determine the set of all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ for which $(z^i)^2=(z^2)^i$.

My ideas:

I took the principle branch to be $\text{Arg}(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ and let $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

Then
$$\Large{(z^2)^i=e^{i\ln{r^2}}e^{-\text{Arg}(e^{i2\theta})}}$$
and
$$\Large{(z^i)^2=e^{i\ln{r^2}}e^{-2\text{Arg}(e^{i\theta})}}=\Large{e^{i\ln{r^2}}e^{-2\theta}}.$$
Then we would need 
$$2\theta=\text{Arg}(e^{i2\theta}).$$
From here wee need $-\frac{\pi}{2}<\text{Arg}(z)\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $z\neq0$.

I think this is correct. Does anyone have another way of going about it? Maybe less computational.